# SAML SSO for webapp hosted in different domain than the Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using SAML SSO for my webapp using WSO2 Identity Server. Both the webapp and IS is hosted in same domain. Now I want to separate them. When I did that, SAML SSO related cookies are missing due to different domains. Log out fails. So how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

SAML was exactly made to support cross domain single sign on and single logout. It does not rely on shared cookie domains. Please elaborate a little more what exactly you are doing and what is not working.